# Check if div has appended element

Tags: jquery, if-statement

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
  var userValue = $('#textarea').val();
  $('#textarea').val('');
 $('#writtings').append('<p>' + userValue + '</p>');

});

$('body').on('click', '#delete', function() {
     $("#writtings p").remove();
     return false;  
  });
  
 if($('#writtings').is(':empty') ) {
  $("#delete").css("background","red");
 }else {
   $("#delete").css("background","green");
 }
```

```css
#writtings {
  margin-top:20px;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  id="textarea" placeholder="Write here!"></textarea>    
 <button id="add">Add</button>
 <button id="delete">Delete</button>
 <div id="writtings"></div>
```

Guys i wanna check if my div has appended  element or not.Cos i change my button background if there is an appended element.So how to?[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxx50up8/)

Comment: Seems ok. What is your problem?

Comment: Seems ok? If you add , delete button's background is not green @Azim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var userValue = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#textarea').val('');
    $('#writtings').append('<p>' + userValue + '</p>');
     if($('#writtings p')) {
        $("#delete").css("background","red");
     } 
     else {
     $("#delete").css("background","green");
     }
});

$('body').on('click', '#delete', function() {
     $("#writtings p").remove();
     $("#delete").css("background","green");
     return false;  
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qxx50up8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add `$("#delete").css("background","green")` in the click event of `add` button like below.

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var userValue = $('#textarea').val();
    if(!userValue) retrun;

    $('#textarea').val('');
    $('#writtings').append('<p>' + userValue + '</p>');

    $("#delete").css("background","green");
});
```

And add `$("#delete").css("background", "red");` in the click event of `delete` button like below.

```
$('body').on('click', '#delete', function() {
    $("#writtings p").remove();
    $("#delete").css("background", "red");

    return false;  
});
```

Comment: First:if there is no appended element delete button must be red.  Second:if not delete button must be green. Also if i delete appended elements button background wont be updated right?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can check p tag is appended to #writtings div by this code:-

```
  if($('#writtings').find('p').length == 1 ) {
          $("#delete").css("background","red");
         }else {
           $("#delete").css("background","green");
    }
```